# I need help simplifying a sum problem that involves a binomial raised to a power

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, exponential-sum

I have come across a problem in my homework that describes the sum of a binomial squared, and I can't think of a way to simplify it. I have an idea that it would involve $\frac{\left(n\right)\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{6}$, but I can't seem to format the equation in a way that would be helpful. Any help would be much appreciated. There are two problems below, a solution to either would be amazing.

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)}{2}-i\right)^2}{n}$
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)}{2}-i\right)^2$

Comment: Square the binomial first: $\displaystyle\;\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)^2}{4}-(n+1)\,i+i^2\right) = \ldots\;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)}{2}-i\right)^2\\
&=\frac14\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(n+1-2i\right)^2\\
&=\frac14\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}((n+1)^2-4(n+1)i+4i^2)\\
&=\frac14\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n+1)^2-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n+1)i+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2\\
&=\frac14n(n+1)^2-\frac12 n(n-1)(n+1)+\frac16 (n-1)n(2n-1)\\
&=\dfrac{n}{12}\left( 3(n+1)^2-6(n-1)(n+1)+2 (n-1)(2n-1)\right)\\
&=\dfrac{n}{12}\left( 3n^2+6n+3-6(n^2-1)+2(2n^2-3n+1)\right)\\
&=\dfrac{n}{12}\left( 3n^2+6n+3-6n^2+6+4n^2-6n+2\right)\\
&=\dfrac{n}{12}\left( n^2+11\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the help! The problem checks, but I was just curious as to how you solved each of the sums in step 4.

Comment: does it have something to do with sum of a series, and if so how? @martycohen

Comment: Well known sums: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = n(n-1)/2, \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2 = n(n-1)(2n-1)/6$.